# Ubuntu 19.04 .bash_profile doesn't exists

Tags: files, .profile

I'm trying to setup the WP-CLI completion from their [site](https://wp-cli.org/#tab-completions)
but I couldn't find the `~/.bash_profile` file in my home directory and I tried the instructions with the `~/.bashrc` file, I followed the zsh instructions too but it didn't work. Is it normal that there is no .bash_profile? Is it good if I create it manually?
[Terminal Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRMjI.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it normal that there is no .bash_profile?

Yes it is - the default files copied from `/etc/skel` during account creation by `adduser` are:

```
$ ls -A /etc/skel
.bash_logout  .bashrc  .config  .kshrc  .mkshrc  .profile  Templates
```

As you can see, there is a default `.bash_logout` but no default `.bash_profile`.

> Is it good if I create it manually?

Yes that's fine - be aware that if you do so, it will be read in preference to the `~/.profile` file - from the `INVOCATION` section of `man bash`:

> ```
>    When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a  non-inter‐
>    active  shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes com‐
>    mands from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists.   After  reading
>    that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile,
>    in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one  that
>    exists  and  is  readable.  The --noprofile option may be used when the
>    shell is started to inhibit this behavior.
> ```

so you may wish to source `~/.profile` from the new `~/.bash_profile` in order to maintain any functionality that it provides.